# cannot host django project in local network

Tags: django, localhost, local-network

I wanted to acess the web page that i did in django in all devices(mobile and desktop) connected in my network, i tried:

1. just python manage.py runserver and acess the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ given by the console.    The chrome of my mobile gives me "connection refused"
2. put the ip in ALLOWED_HOST and python manage.py runserver my_ip:8000   my_ip is the number of my ip that the https://www.whatismyip.com/ gives me.
3. python manage.py runserver 0:8000, it gives me [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

what can i do?

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes, i'm on Windows 10

Comment: Press ```windows key + r``` then type in ```cmd```. In the command promt type ```ipconfig``` which will give you your ipv4. That is what you can type in to your ```ALLOWED_HOSTS``` in the ```settings.py```. Then to run the server just run the comman ```python manage.py runserver my_ip:8000```

Comment: It gives you that error when you run the ipconfig? Or when you try to run the server?

Comment: IPV4 worked for me, thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: i tried this and python manage.py runserver, the chrome of my mobile gives me connection refused